# How to create physical and logical volumes on system reboot

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, lvm, mdadm

My system is set up so that I take four devices, create a RAID 10 array out of them, create a physical volume, a volume group, and then three logical volumes, and lastly I create filesystems out of the logical volumes and mount them on my filesystem.

I know that `mdadm.conf` exists to locate (or maybe recreate?) the RAID10 device on a restart of the system, and I know that `fstab` exists to remount the logical volumes on the filesystem. However, I'm a little confused as to how to recreate the physical volume, volume group, and logical volumes on restart of the system. Is it the case that the volumes already exist on the RAID 10 device once it is located by its UUID and name so that I do not need to create them again, or is there some kind of configuration I need to set so that they are automatically created?

Comment: If LVM is setup properly this should be automatic.  The tools create signatures on the various partitions that are detected when the system starts.

Answer (score 0):

Newer versions of mdadm don't bother with mdadm.conf any more - they scan for superblocks and assemble what arrays they find. Most distros have a startup hook for this.

Once up, your arrays will contain inactive volume groups which, again, should be activated by LVM during startup. If not, the command

```
vgchange -ay
```

will enable all your volumes.

Comment: A couple questions: 1. How do I check whether a volume group is active or not? 2. If volumes are inactive on reboot, where can I put `vgchange -ay` so that it is called after the kernel locates the RAID device but before the filesystem in `fstab` is mounted?

Comment: Is your root, or a partition like /usr which you need at boot time, on LVM like this?

Comment: I don't think so. Looks like root is just an ext4 filesystem from the `/dev/xvda1` device

Comment: But I'm honestly not sure, it's an Amazon Linux so a lot of stuff was preconfigured.

Comment: Also my system can no longer seem to locate the RAID device. When I run `sudo mdadm -Q /dev/sdh1` the output is `/dev/sdh1: is not an md array
/dev/sdh1: device 0 in 4 device unknown raid10 array.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail`

Comment: /dev/sdh is a physical device - a component of the array. The array itself will wind up something like /dev/md0.

Comment: I know but `/dev/md0` does not exist

Comment: btw `[ -r /proc/mdstat -a -r /dev/md/md-device-map ] && /sbin/mdadm -IRs` is inside my `rc.sysinit` file, but I don't have a `/dev/md` directory. Plus it looks like `vgchange` is called in `rc.sysinit`

Comment: What does `mdadm -s` tell you?

Comment: `$ sudo mdadm -s`
`mdadm: -s does not set the mode, and so cannot be the first option.`

Comment: Sorry, that should've been `mdadm -D -s`

Comment: doesn't seem to output anything

Comment: check this out: `$sudo mdadm -E -s /dev/sdh1`
`ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=2854c8d5:8d850f9f:9d72d1db:bd3d6e93 name=domU-12-31-39-09-CC-E6:0`